# when i try to run Hello Agent for second time this Error happen

Tags: java, runtime, agents-jade

First time that i run it, it works but second time it shows jade.core.Runtime.
if i close the eclipse and open it, it run okay but second time it happens again.

```
import jade.core.Agent;
public class Asadi extends Agent {
@Override
protected void setup() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
                    }
                }
```

after second time this error shows.

```
May 04, 2020 5:46:03 AM jade.Boot parseCmdLineArgs
WARNING: WARNING: ignoring command line argument , occurring after agents specification
May 04, 2020 5:46:03 AM jade.core.Runtime beginContainer
INFO: ----------------------------------
    This is JADE 4.5.0 - revision 6825 of 23-05-2017 10:06:04
    downloaded in Open Source, under LGPL restrictions,
    at http://jade.tilab.com/
----------------------------------------
May 04, 2020 5:46:04 AM jade.imtp.leap.CommandDispatcher addICP
WARNING: Error adding ICP jade.imtp.leap.JICP.JICPPeer@65ae6ba4[Cannot bind server socket to localhost port 1099].
May 04, 2020 5:46:04 AM jade.core.AgentContainerImpl joinPlatform
SEVERE: Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active
jade.core.IMTPException: No ICP active
    at jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager.initialize(LEAPIMTPManager.java:138)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.init(AgentContainerImpl.java:321)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:499)
    at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
    at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
May 04, 2020 5:46:04 AM jade.core.Runtime$1 run
INFO: JADE is closing down now.
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: Can you check the port `1099` before your second run

Comment: tnx. the port was the problem.
when i didnt mention it, automatically choose port 1099 and when i change it, it works.
but for each port, it works just ine time and i'm forced to change it for each use.

Comment: @Farshad How did you change the port?